# Angular 4 - Adding a class & path to svg inside a component?

Tags: angular, svg, angular-cli

How do I add a class and the path dynamically to a SVG in **Angular 4** when it's inside a component?

In my component, when I paste the following code into the component template the icon works;

```
<svg class="another-class iconId">

<use xlink:href="/icon-path/def.svg#iconId"></use>

</svg>
```

But when I try to bind a class like this:

```
<svg class="another-class {{iconId}}">

<use xlink:href="/icon-path/def.svg#{{iconId}}"></use>

</svg>
```

I get errors:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to ':xlink:href' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:use'
```

After searching around, I found suggestions to change the code to this:

```
<svg class="another-class {{iconId}}">

<svg:use [attr.xlink:href]="/icon-path/def.svg#{{iconId}}"></svg:use>

</svg>
```

With that I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 30 in [/icon-path/def.svg#{{iconId}}]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** Tried the following as Noodle suggested:

```
<svg class="another-class {{iconId}}">

<use [attr.xlink:href]="'/icon-path/def.svg#' + iconId"></use>

</svg>
```

Still getting the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'className' of object '[object SVGSVGElement]'
```

In that code when I removed `{{iconId}}` from `<svg class="another-class {{iconId}}">` there are no errors, but the svg icon doesn't show either.

Comment: `[attr.xlink:href]="'/icon-path/def.svg#'+iconId"` no need to add `{{}}` when using bindings.

Comment: @n00dl3 Hi. Tried it. Still getting an error. I updated my answer with the results.

Comment: It seems you forgot the braces. For the class, just use ngClass instead :`[ngClass]="iconId"`.

Comment: Sorry. The braces were there in my code. I forgot to add them here. And adding ngClass throws an error: Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:svg'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is working for Angular 6:

```
<svg [ngClass]="'another-class ' + iconId">
  <use [attr.xlink:href]="'/icon-path/def.svg#' + iconId"></use>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

use ngClass

```
[ngClass]="iconId"
[ngClass]="iconId ? iconId : ''"
[attr.xlink:href]="'/icon-path/def.svg#' + iconId"
```

Import this in AppModule. I remember it fixed for me in Angular2 but don't know in Angular4.

```
import { CommonModule }       from '@angular/common';
```

Comment: Hi. I get the following error when I do that: Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:svg'.

Comment: Hi no. To get it to work I had to change it like this: [ngClass]="iconName ? iconName : ''". Otherwise there was an error saying I'm missing a colon. And after that I still get the error: Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:svg'

Comment: I got same issue some times, can't remember how i fixed it. I'll return after I find the fix.

Comment: Thank you!! I've been struggling with this all day :(

Comment: check import { CommonModule }       from '@angular/common';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155247/discussion-between-shadowfoorm-and-user3607282).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<svg [class]="getIconClass(iconId)">
    <svg:use [attr.xlink:href]="getIconPath(iconId)"></svg:use>
</svg>
```

create the functions:

```
getIconPath(iconId) {
    return '/icon-path/def.svg#' + iconId;
}

getIconClass(iconId) {
    return 'another-class ' + iconId;
}
```

I have modified an existing [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rjEYI4thCYvqalP67QWT?p=preview) to show the above function usage

Also look at this helpful [post](http://blog.500tech.com/svg-in-angular-2/)

Comment: Tried it. There are no errors but the icon doesn't show either.